# Exclude slf4j-jdk14 from maven-failsage-plugin

Tags: maven-3, slf4j

We have a new Maven project where we are facing an issue when we use the exec-maven-plugin to start our process via a maven profile. The process start-up is failing with the error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: LoggerFactory is not a Logback LoggerContext but Logback is on the classpath. Either remove Logback or the competing implementation (class org.slf4j.impl.JDK14LoggerFactory loaded from file:/C:/Users/xxxxxxxxxxxx/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-jdk14/1.5.6/slf4j-jdk14-1.5.6.jar). If you are using WebLogic you will need to add 'org.slf4j' to prefer-application-packages in WEB-INF/weblogic.xml Object of class [org.slf4j.impl.JDK14LoggerFactory] must be an instance of class ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext
```

When we tried removing all reference to logback-classic jar, the process starts fine although we lose the logging functionality as it comes down to basic logging by SLF4J.

So, all references to slf4j-jdk14 were removed from the POM and the dependency tree has been verified too. It was then found that the maven plugins were pulling in the slf4j-jdk14 jar.

1. **maven-jar-plugin** - downgrading it from 2.6 to 2.4 did the trick here
2. **maven-failsafe-plugin & maven-resources-plugin** - we could not find a way with these plugin. Upgrading / downgrading didnt work (or may be we couldnt find the exact usable version)

> So the real question : How can we exclude slf4j-jdk14 jar from the maven plugins?

The following has been tried and doesn't seem to work:

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
<version>${maven-failsafe-plugin.version}</version>
<executions>
    <execution>
    <id>integration-test</id>
    <configuration>
        <includes>
        <include>**/*IT.java</include>
        </includes>
    </configuration>
    <goals>
        <goal>integration-test</goal>
        <goal>verify</goal>
    </goals>
    </execution>
</executions>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.6</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Also, Googling didn't help much. Any pointer would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Midhun

Comment: Maven was downloading version 1.5.6 of slf4j-jdk - hence that version has been used for exclusion. I am not very sure which version of slf4j is the maven-failsafe-plugin using.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution for the myself by looking at the docs of the plugin. In the exec-maven-plugin, there is an option to exclude the dependencies of the plugins. I put in the same in the configuration and it worked !

```
<configuration>
    <includePluginDependencies>false</includePluginDependencies>
</configuration>
```

Midhun